# nodejs mongodb не хочет выбирать поля

Tags: node.js, mongodb, find

Выводит все поля, хотя я выбираю только message

```
database.collection('gggg').find({ token: 'admin' }, { message: 1}).toArray().then(function(asd){ console.log(asd) });
```

результат:

```
    [ { _id: 5b4e01260b44f542b40100b7,
token: 'admin',
ids: 45685,
message: '555' },
{ _id: 5b4e059db0df7d2cd48acda4,
token: 'admin',
ids: 2344,
message: '555' } ]
```

хотя по идее должен выводить:

```
    [ { _id: 5b4e01260b44f542b40100b7,
    message: '555' },
    { _id: 5b4e059db0df7d2cd48acda4,
    message: '555' } ]
```

что я делаю не так ?

Answer (score 0):

так работает для меня:

```
database.collection('gggg').find({ token: 'admin' }).project({_id:0}).toArray().then(function(asd){ console.log(asd) });
```